# How to take values from Formik inside a hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, use-ref

I am using Formik in my app. I need to take values from Formik and use it inside my hook.

Currently I am doing it using `useRef` hook

Following is my custom hook code which requires `Formik` values

```
const { doRequest, errors } = useRequest({
    url: "my_url",
    method: "post",
    body: {
      mobileNumber: formikRef.current
        ? formikRef.current.values.mobileNumber
        : "",
      password: formikRef.current ? formikRef.current.values.password : "",
    },
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      console.log("Hi" + response.msg);
      Router.push("/");
    },
    onFailure: (response) => {
      console.log("Hi2" + response.msg);
    },
  });
```

In the body, the mobile number and password is always empty even though I enter values in my textfield. I am calling the `doRequest` method inside `onSubmit` of `Formik`

I am asking the ref using following

```
 <Formik
            innerRef={formikRef}..
```

If I had used `useState` for all my fields It would have been extremely easy to pass those values to my custom hook but due to large form and validation , I am using Formik

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `innerRef`. You can simply use formik `values`.

- Your custom hook should return `doRequest` which accepts a param so that it can catch dynamic values.
- write the hook in such a way that it caters to both static values and dynamic values. [See the closed github issue here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2527)

**working demo**

[image: Edit formik pass values to custom hook]

**Code snippet**

```js
export default () => {
  const { doRequest, errors } = useRequest({
    url: "my_url",
    method: "post",
    body: {
      mobileNumber: "0000",
      password: "xxxx"
    },
    onSuccess: response => {
      console.log("Hi" + response.msg);
      // Router.push("/");
    },
    onFailure: response => {
      console.log("Hi2" + response.msg);
    }
  });

  const handleSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    doRequest(values);
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-12">
      <h1>My Form</h1>
      <Formik initialValues={{ mobileNumber: "" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {({ errors }) => (
          <Form>
            <Field name="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
            <Field name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <div className="messages-wrapper">
              {errors.email && (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                  <ErrorMessage name="mobileNumber" />
                </div>
              )}
              {errors.password && (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                  <ErrorMessage name="password" />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: but in the body how do I pass parameters?

Comment: @Nudge which module do you use for `useRequest `? the npm module might already support what you need, but you always can add local state with `useState` and update it in `handleSubmit ` right before `doRequest `

Comment: @MaxGram I am not using any module. I have created my own hook

Answer (score 0):

You can get any value from the Formik bag via the [`useFormikContext()`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormikContext) hook. Like so:

```
const { values } = useFormikContext();
const { mobileNumber } = values;
```

Comment: I got `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useFormikContext.resetForm')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the predefined `useFormikContext()` hook provided by `Formik` or you could set a ref to Formik and use its current value to fetch `Formik` form values.